# How to find what page an element would be on with pagingandsortingrepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I want to provide my users with the ability to go to specific page of elements by an elements id.  I was wondering if it is possible with the spring `pagingandsortingrepository` to find a specific page without the page number?  I want to the user to still be able to interact with the full paginated result set.  This is my first time using pagination in an application let alone the fact that I am new to spring in general.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "to find a specific page without the page number"

Comment: To get a page from the pagingandsortingrepository you need to provide a pageable object to whatever find method you are using and to create an instance of the pageable class you need the page number and page size.  However, I need to go to a specific page in the paginated results with out necessarily knowing what page number the element I’m linking to is on.